# React Display Mispelled components in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I created a WeatherApp Component using React in VSCode IDE.

However, I mispelled WeatherApp below, adding in extra/text digits. How can I get VSCode to display mispelled components?

I have ESLint and ReactCodeJS snippets extensions installed. Its giving a compilation error at command prompt, however no red underlined text is showing in IDE. How can have it displayed as error/warning in VSCode?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import WeatherApp from './WeatherApp';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <WeatherTest1234App />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Needs more info... needs `package.json` and `root` folder structure. Can you share with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have a **.eslintrc.js** in you project something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2021: true,
    },
    extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:react/recommended'],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
        },
        ecmaVersion: 12,
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: ['react'],
    rules: {
        quotes: ['error', 'single'],
        semi: ['error', 'never'],
        'react/jsx-uses-react': 'off',
        'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing `eslint` extension doesn't mean that the plugin itself is working for your project.

You need to run commands to setup the configurations. These configurations will then be added to your project in a file called `eslint.js`

https://medium.com/@RossWhitehouse/setting-up-eslint-in-react-c20015ef35f7

After you have set up everything correctly following the steps above, you should see `eslint` on the bottom right of your VSCode IDE.

[image: VsCode Eslint IDE]

Finally, you should see something like this:
[image]